# How to XOR literal with a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement the [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) algorithm in Python.  The way I understand it, I have to use a key like "abcd" and then XOR it with a hexadecimal array (cycling the key if necessary)

```
P = (
      0x243f6a88, 0x85a308d3, 0x13198a2e, 0x03707344, 0xa4093822, 0x299f31d0,
      0x082efa98, 0xec4e6c89, 0x452821e6, 0x38d01377, 0xbe5466cf, 0x34e90c6c,
      0xc0ac29b7, 0xc97c50dd, 0x3f84d5b5, 0xb5470917, 0x9216d5d9, 0x8979fb1b,
    )
```

The data types here have me very confused.  I saw somewhere that 'abcd' = 0x61626364.  In that case, XORing the first element of P would simply be 0x61626364 ^ 0x243f6a88.

So, how do I convert a string like 'abcd' to the format 0x?????.  or perhaps there's a better way?  Any light on this would be very appreciated!

Comment: Look up hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: Don't think about strings. It's just arrays of bytes. The key is basically a single large integer. Blowfish allows variable length for the key, so you'll also want to use a byte array for the key.

Comment: Also "abcd" can be interpreted many different ways. 0xabcd is a perfectly valid 16-bit integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a string to an array of bytes:

```
b = bytes('abcd', 'ascii')
```

To convert array of bytes to int:

```
i = int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

Comment: Second line gives me the error `TypeError: Required argument 'byteorder' (pos 2) not found`

Comment: @Ben try byteorder instead of byte_order ?

Answer (score 3):

Two hexadecimal digits can encode exactly one byte.  This makes sense, because each hexadecimal digit can be in `16` different states, so two hexadecimal digits can be in `16 * 16 = 256` different states, which is exactly the same as the number of states representable in a single byte.

Because ASCII characters can *also* be encoded in a single byte, any ASCII character can be encoded as two hexadecimal digits.

For example, the letter `a` has character code `97` in ASCII.  Converting the decimal number `97` to base 16 (hexadecimal) gives you `0x61`.

You can therefore take any string and convert it into a hexadecimal number by taking every character and representing it as two hex digits in your number.  Looking at your example above, `a = 0x61`, `b = 0x62`, `c = 0x63`, and `d = 0x64`.  Putting these all together gives you the representation `abcd = 0x61626364`.

Comment: Very helpful.  So, in Python, how do I go from `'abcd'` to `0x61626364`?